# Decoding escaped unicode

Tags: java, unicode

I am reading the following String from a file:

```
a \\u0645 b
```

I want to process is so that when it is printed to the console it looks like:

`a م b`

How can I do that?

Comment: Is it actually a compile time literal that is incorrectly escaped and you don't have the ability to just fix it....?  It gets converted by the compiler, so you can't just take out the backslash at runtime, it would be quite a hassle to "fix" the bad literal at runtime.  Don't understand what the actual issue is.

Comment: Why cannot you just remove the first \?

Comment: The double backslashes are given. I read them from a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to decode it two times.
Try to use [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Decoding it once was sufficient, though.